# В чем разница между presenter'ом и interactor'ом в чистой архитектуре?

Tags: архитектура

Разбираюсь с чистой архитектурой. Не доходит один момент: на сколько я понимаю цепочка работает примерно так:

> controller <-> persenter <-> interactor <-> repository

Если рассмотреть это на примере метода, то получается, что контроллер вызывает метод `presenter->getBooks()`, далее презентер вызывает интерактор: `interactor->getBooks()` и только потом происходит обращение к репозиторию.

При этом, presenter и interactor просто вызывают один и тот же метод. Так в чем же их разница?

Скорее всего подразумевается, что в них должна происходить некая обработка данных перед возвратом результата функции, но какая логика и где должна выполняться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Clean Architecture** подразумевает, что код разделен на 4 уровня со следующим правилом зависимости: внутренний уровень не должен зависеть от каких-либо внешних уровней. Это означает, что зависимости должны указываться внутри каждого уровня, чтобы не было зависимостей между уровнями (слоями).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно сущности **Presenter** и **Interactor(Use Cases)** лежат на разных уровнях и несут разную смысловую и функциональную нагрузку.

**Presenter** обрабатывает события от пользовательского интерфейса (UI) и работают как callbaсk-и из внутренних уровней (**Interactors**). **Presenters** являются легко тестируемыми объектами и их основная задача -  получить данные от приложения и преобразовать их так, чтобы Представление (**View**) могло просто переместить их на экран.

**Interactor** же фактически содержит бизнес-логику приложения (проверка каких либо условий и обработка данных). Они работают в фоновом режиме и передают события и данные верхнему уровню (**Presenters**) c помощью callbaсk-ов. Это полностью соответствует принципу единственной ответственности, который гласит, что каждый объект должен иметь одну ответственность и эта ответственность должна быть полностью инкапсулирована в класс. Все его поведения должны быть направлены исключительно на обеспечение этой ответственности.

Например над проектом работает несколько команд, каждая из которых разрабатывает код на определенных слоях. Когда разработчики компонента **Presenter**-а поменяют что-то в коде и захотят протестировать его,
им просто нужно собрать свою версию **Presenter**-а с версиями компонентов
**Interactors** и **Entities**, используемыми в данный момент. Никакой другой компонент в системе им не потребуется для этого. Это означает, что разработчикам **Presenters** не придется прилагать значительных усилий для подготовки к тестированию и им достаточно учесть небольшое количество переменных. Вышеописанный пример легко проследить на диаграмме компонентов, представленной ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень важно заметить, что в такой диаграмме компонентов есть особенность: с какого бы компонента вы ни начали, вы не сможете пройти по связям-зависимостям и вернуться обратно в этот же компонент. Эта структура не имеет циклов - то есть это ациклический ориентированный граф.

Comment: Спасибо,прекрасный ответ и прекрасный вопрос.